# Reference a form by name

Tags: jquery, forms

How can I reference a form by name using JQuery?

I have 3 different forms with the same name, `author-form`. I have used this function but it only works with the ID field of the form. Why should I create 3 separate functions when I can create one, using the same form name for all three forms?

```
$('#author-form').submit(function() {

    var action = $("author-form").attr('action');        
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/zabjournal/pages/author/progress.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response) {

            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("form[name='author-form']")
```

Should work

Answer (score 2):

assuming your forms are named `name1`, `name2` and `name3` you could do in this way

```
$('form[name="name1"], form[name="name3"], form[name="name3"]').submit(function(evt) {

    var action = $(this).attr('action');        
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/zabjournal/pages/author/progress.php",
              /* or probably you may want instead <url: action> */
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response) {

            }
        });
    return false; /* or evt.preventDefault() */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can target attribute names like this:

```
$('form[name="author-form"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
 $('form[name=author-form]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$('form[name="author-form"]').submit(function()...
```

Works for inputs atleast, never tried on a form.